# Отсортировать слова в массиве используя алгоритм выбора, метод compareTo() java

Tags: java

Я только начал изучать Java и наткнулся на некоторую задачку в теме со строками.

Вот ее суть:

> Написать программу, которая считывает введенный с клавиатуры текст до
>   слова "end". После чего отсортировать введенные слова используя
>   алгоритм выбора, метод compareTo().

У меня возникли следующие вопросы:

1.Можно ли реализовать через StringBuilder, если да, то как это сделать?

2.Если только через массив со словами, то как осуществить сортировку методом выборки?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word;
    boolean check = true;
    System.out.print("Введите слова, если будет введено слово 'end', ввод закончится");
    while(check) {
        word = sc.nextLine();
        if (word == "end") {
            check = false;
        }
        list.add(word);
    }
}
```

Все к чему я дошел. Но мой вариант мне не нравится. Хотел бы спросить у знающих людей нет ли альтернативы

Comment: Уточните в вопросе таки фильтрация или сортировка?

Comment: @gil9red Простите, опечатался. Сортировка

Comment: Ничего страшного, просто исправьте свою опечатку. Под вопросом тыкните на кнопку `править` :) А так, я могу сказать что вам проще будет составить массив или список строк и отсортировать их стандартными способами: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[]) или https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)

Comment: @gil9red Да но суть задачи немного в другом) Спасибо за совет)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word;
    boolean check = true;
    System.out.print("Введите слова, если будет введено слово 'end', ввод закончится:\n");
    while (check){
        word=sc.nextLine();
        if (word.equals("end")){
            check = false;
            break;
        }
        list.add(word);
    }
    list.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Вариант через вставки с использвоаним compareTo.
По каждой итерации проверяем значение метода, если оно меньше, то и слово считаем "меньше" после чего двигаем его на позиции выше в массиве.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word;
    System.out.print("Введите слова, если будет введено слово 'end', ввод закончится:\n");
    while (true) {
        word = sc.nextLine();
        if (word.equals("end")){
            break;
        }
        list.add(word);
    }
    selectionSort(list);
    System.out.println(list);
}

private static void selectionSort (List<String> array){
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
        int min_i = i;
        String temp = array.get(i);
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.size(); j++){
            int resTemp = array.get(j).compareTo(temp);
            if (resTemp < 0) {
                temp = array.get(j);
                min_i = j;
            }
        }
        if (i != min_i) {
            String tmp = array.get(i);
            array.set(i, array.get(min_i));
            array.set(min_i, tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что `list.sort()` сортирует выбором? Я уверен, что нет.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Может подскажете вы конкретно по сортировке?)))

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець не учел этого, так же добавил метод вставки.

Comment: Да какой "вставки"?

Comment: @MBo "метод сортировки выбором" имел ввиду

Answer (score 3):

В цикле ввода, вероятно, неточная логика - слово `end` вряд ли требуется вводить в список

```
if (word == "end")
     check = false;
 else
     list.add(word);
```

StringBuilder здесь ни к чему, работа ведь ведутся с отдельным словами.

Сортировка выбором описана в сотне мест. Вот произвольный пример - вам нужно лишь модифицировать, используя `compareTo` и ArrayList строк вместо массива

```
public static void selectionSort (int[] numbers){
    int min, temp;

    for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length-1; index++){
        min = index;
        for (int scan = index+1; scan < numbers.length; scan++){
            if (numbers[scan] < numbers[min])
                min = scan;
        }

        // Swap the values
        temp = numbers[min];
        numbers[min] = numbers[index];
        numbers[index] = temp;
    }
}
```